# How to convert Quickoboks online api report object into xml file?

Tags: xml, api, response, quickbooks-online

With the help of C# SDK of Intuit Quickbooks online I am getting the response of api call for PNL report. But I want to save this response in xml file.

I Currently data SerializationFormat is Json. I tried to change json to Xml but it gives the errors.

```
private  void GetReportAndPrintToConsole(ServiceContext qboServiceContext, String reportName, String startDate, String endDate)
        {


            //JSON required for QBO Reports API
            qboServiceContext.IppConfiguration.Message.Request.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json; qboServiceContext.IppConfiguration.Message.Response.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;

            //Instantiate ReportService
            ReportService reportsService = new ReportService(qboServiceContext);

            //Set properties for Report
            reportsService.start_date = startDate;
            reportsService.end_date = endDate;

            //Execute Report API call
            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Report report = reportsService.ExecuteReport(reportName);



            Console.WriteLine(report.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted to save the Profit and Loss report in XML format but I was getting `Report` object from the api so I have to write the code manually to get the XML.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/sambhal/qeBpo) is the code snippet that can be used by anyone to convert `Report` object into XML string.

**After this line**

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Report report = reportsService.ExecuteReport(reportName);
```

**Call function like this**

```
string xmlstring = getReportInXML(report);
```

Or directly copy paste from here

```
#region Get XML From Report object 
/*==================================================
=            Get XML From Report object            =
==================================================*/
private string getReportInXML(Report report)
{
    string strreport = "";
    strreport += "<Report xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\">";
    strreport += getReportHeader(report.Header);
    strreport += getReportColumns(report.Columns);
    strreport += getRows(report.Rows);
    strreport += "</Report>";
    return strreport;
}
private string getReportHeader(ReportHeader header)
{
    string strheader = "";
    strheader += "<Header>";
    strheader += "<Time>" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:sszzz}", header.Time) + "</Time>";
    strheader += "<ReportName>" + header.ReportName + "</ReportName>";
    strheader += "<DateMacro>" + header.DateMacro + "</DateMacro>";
    strheader += "<ReportBasis>" + header.ReportBasis + "</ReportBasis>";
    strheader += "<StartPeriod>" + header.StartPeriod + "</StartPeriod>";
    strheader += "<EndPeriod>" + header.EndPeriod + "</EndPeriod>";
    strheader += "<SummarizeColumnsBy>" + header.SummarizeColumnsBy + "</SummarizeColumnsBy>";
    strheader += "<Currency>" + header.Currency + "</Currency>";
    foreach (var option in header.Option)
    {
        strheader += "<Option>";
        strheader += "<Name>" + option.Name + "</Name>";
        strheader += "<Value>" + option.Value + "</Value>";
        strheader += "</Option>";
    }
    strheader += "</Header>";
    return strheader;
}
private string getReportColumns(Column[] columns)
{
    string strcolumn = "";
    strcolumn += "<Columns>";
    foreach (Column column in columns)
    {
        strcolumn += "<Column>";
        strcolumn += " <ColTitle>" + Convert.ToString(column.ColTitle) + "</ColTitle>";
        strcolumn += " <ColType>" + column.ColType + "</ColType>";
        foreach (var meta in column.MetaData)
        {
            strcolumn += "<MetaData>";
            strcolumn += "<Name>" + meta.Name + "</Name>";
            strcolumn += "<Value>" + meta.Value + "</Value>";
            strcolumn += "</MetaData>";
        }
        strcolumn += "</Column>";
    }
    strcolumn += "</Columns>";
    return strcolumn;
}
private string getRows(Row[] rows)
{
    string strrows = "";
    strrows += " <Rows>";
    foreach (Row row in rows)
    {
        if (row.type.ToString() == "Section")                    ///It contains more Rows
        {
            // if type of row is data then call it
            strrows += getRowSection(row);
        }
        else if (row.type.ToString() == "Data")
        {
            //Otherwise call getRowSection
            strrows += getRowData(row);
        }
    }
    strrows += " </Rows>";
    return strrows;
}
private string getRowSection(Row row)
{
    string strrowsection = "";
    strrowsection += " <Row type=\"Section\"";
    if (row.group != null)
    {
        strrowsection += " group=\"" + row.group + "\"";
    }
    strrowsection += ">";
    string type = row.AnyIntuitObjects[0].GetType().ToString();
    object[] objs = (object[])row.AnyIntuitObjects;
    foreach (var obj in objs)
    {
        string objtype = obj.GetType().ToString();
        switch (objtype)
        {
            case "Intuit.Ipp.Data.Header":
                Header header = (Header)obj;
                strrowsection += getHeader(header);
                break;
            case "Intuit.Ipp.Data.Rows":
                Rows rows = (Rows)obj;
                strrowsection += getRows(rows.Row);
                break;
            case "Intuit.Ipp.Data.Summary":
                Summary summary = (Summary)obj;
                strrowsection += getSummary(summary);
                break;
        }
    }
    strrowsection += " </Row>";
    return strrowsection;
}
private string getSummary(Summary summary)
{
    string strsummary = "";
    strsummary += "<Summary>";
    ColData[] coldata = (ColData[])summary.ColData;
    strsummary += getColData(coldata);
    strsummary += "</Summary>";
    return strsummary;
}
private string getRowData(Row row)
{
    string strrowdata = "";
    strrowdata += " <Row type=\"Data\">";
    ColData[] coldata = (ColData[])row.AnyIntuitObjects[0];
    strrowdata += getColData(coldata);
    strrowdata += "</Row>";
    return strrowdata;
}
private string getHeader(Header header)
{
    string strheader = "";
    strheader += "   <Header>";
    ColData[] coldata = (ColData[])header.ColData;
    strheader += getColData(coldata);
    strheader += "   </Header>";
    return strheader;
}
private string getColData(ColData[] coldata)
{
    string strcoldata = "";
    foreach (ColData col in coldata)
    {
        //Generate the coldata string here.
        string value = col.value;
        value = value.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        strcoldata += "<ColData value=\"" + value + "\"";
        if (col.id != null)
        {
            strcoldata += " id=\"" + col.id + "\"";
        }
        strcoldata += " /> ";
    }
    return strcoldata;
}
/*=====  End of Get XML From Report object  ======*/
#endregion  End of Get XML From Report object
```